# Access to image src attribute from click event on other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that gettng clicked (remove button) that is positioned after `img` on my page.

```
     <div class="item">
           <img src="/media/BodyPart_e4fc6673-1476-42d2-a98d-947b0e79fd99/300/0" class="media-item">
           <div class="remove" title="Remove"></div> //getting clicked
    </div>
```

so on click event I am accessing the img through this code:

```
var img = $(this).prev("img.media-item");
```

then I want to access to src attribute of `img`

```
var extracted_string = img.src.match(/BodyPart[^\/]*/);
```

but getting `img.src` underfined

how can I fixe that?

> UPDATE

I am just find out that if i will do this `$(this).prev("img.media-item").attr("src")` - i can get the `src`

But why `var img = $(this).prev("img.media-item"); $(img).attr("src")` is not working

Answer (score 1):

A clean way in jQuery to get the `img` from a click in the `.remove` div is like this:

```
$(".remove").click(function(e) {
     var src = $(this).closest(".item").find(".media-item").attr("src");
});
```

The advantage of doing it this way is that it will find the desired image even if the layout is changed somewhat so it doesn't depend on precise relative positioning of elements (making it more robust than techniques that rely on one element being right before another).

This is a very common technique in jQuery code for finding another element in the same branch of the tree as you are in and works well when there are repeated groups of items all with the same structure.  A click on any `.remove` item can operate on any other item in the same branch.

Answer (score 0):

Try this piece of code

```
var imgPath = $('.item img').attr('src');
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are using jQuery, then try:

```
var extracted_string = img.attr('src').match(/BodyPart[^\/]*/);
```